# Need to store more than 4KiB in a session variable in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I need to store more than 4KiB in a session variable, the problem is that the max size of a cookie is 4KiB, what can I do?

Comment: http://www.justinweiss.com/articles/how-rails-sessions-work/

Comment: Why? Can you give more details?